# Not able to add new module in new Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new project in Android Studio (0.4.6), but it does not seem to be generating the structure properly.

The file structure looks correct in the project pane. 
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufTU9.png

Most of the usual settings are missing from the project structure window.
[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcJnG.png

And the so are the module settings. 
[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwaEK.png

When I try to add a new module, there is NOT drop down for what type of module to add.

Instead i just get the same new Project window.

If I through this and create a new module, nothing changes in the Project Structure settings.

Comment: Can you be much more specific about what problems you're having? Please edit your question. It's not clear what you mean by "not seem to be generating the structure properly," nor what you're expecting/getting when adding a new module. Are there compile or syntax errors in shown in the IDE?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/ImjQp2h.png) is what it looks like. All the proper files appear to be there now, but its not recognizing the module as an Android module in the Project Structure window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. Your project is structured correctly, is building correctly, and isn't showing any errors in the IDE. Android Studio doesn't have the same options in Project Structure for module configuration that IntelliJ does for projects not built with Gradle. What you're seeing here is normal and applicable for Gradle-based projects.

Android Studio is more constrained in what types of new modules it allows you to add to a project, because most of the choices IntelliJ offers you either don't make sense for Android projects or can't be implemented properly yet in a Gradle-based project, or both. In Android studio, you can add a module which is an Android application (i.e. APK), an Android library (e.g. a library which can include Android resources and access Android APIs), or a plain Java library (which can't include Android resources or use Android APIs).